# Does this relationship proves that the given positive numbers are equal?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, triangles, real-numbers

Suppose I have six positive numbers divided into two sets given by: $\{a, b, c\}$ and $\{d, e, f\}$. Now, I have relations as:
$$a^2-b^2=d^2-e^2$$
$$b^2-c^2=e^2-f^2$$
$$a^2-c^2=d^2-f^2$$
I some feel that this is only possible when $a=d, b=e, c=f$, also it can be proved easily that the numbers will be identically ordered, i.e., if $a\geq b\geq c$ than $d \geq e \geq f$.

But is there some way to prove that $a=d, b=e, c=f$, One thing we may do is to show triangles created using side lengths $a,b,c$ and $d,e,f$ to be congruent. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Consider $a^2=6$, $b^2=5$, $c^2=4$, $d^2=3$, $e^2=2$, $f^2=1$.